# Postgresql to_char slowing query a by a lot

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to format a column that is timestamp with time zone using to_char since i don't want to include the zone part of the column, but the difference between a query running to_char and without it is like 10 seconds that is a lot of time, i don't have much experience with databases and maybe i'm doing something wrong.

query without to_char time: 1313 ms:

```
select distinct on ("Results"."Timestamp") "Results"."Timestamp", 
"TotalParticlesAccum", "BioAccumulated", "FlowVolume", 
"DCOffsetCh0", "DCOffsetCh1", "DCOffsetCh2", 
"LaserPower", "LaserCurrent", "LaserTemperature", 
"LaserRunHour", "FlowRate", "FlowPressure", 
"FlowTemperature", "CpuTemperature", "PwbTemperature", 
"Temperature1", "Temperature2", "Temperature3", 
"Temperature4", "TotalParticles", "Bio" 
from "Results"
Left join "SensorLog" On "Results"."SampleID" = "SensorLog"."SampleID"
where "Results"."SampleID" = id order by 1 asc;
```

query with to_char time: 12354 ms

```
select distinct on (to_char("Results"."Timestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))     
to_char("Results"."Timestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
"TotalParticlesAccum", "BioAccumulated", "FlowVolume", 
"DCOffsetCh0", "DCOffsetCh1", "DCOffsetCh2", 
"LaserPower", "LaserCurrent", "LaserTemperature", 
"LaserRunHour", "FlowRate", "FlowPressure", 
"FlowTemperature", "CpuTemperature", "PwbTemperature", 
"Temperature1", "Temperature2", "Temperature3", 
"Temperature4", "TotalParticles", "Bio" 
from "Results"
Left join "SensorLog" On "Results"."SampleID" = "SensorLog"."SampleID"
where "Results"."SampleID" = id order by 1 asc;
```

I think I know that the problem is that I have to_char twice, but if i don't have that, it gives me an error 
ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Comment: Show us the output of `explain analyze` for both queries (e.g. uploaded to http://explain.depesz.com) and the definition of the tables including all their indexes

Comment: the reason I use to_char is because the column is with time zone, I don't want the time zone included in the result

Comment: I'm guessing that to_char is preventing postgres from using an index that would otherwise be used. If you post explain info we'll know more.

Comment: `from "Results","SensorLog where "Results"."SampleID" = 839` looks like a Carthesian product to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the fast query with one with the desired format

```
select
    to_char("Timestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as "Timestamp",
    "TotalParticlesAccum", "BioAccumulated", "FlowVolume", 
    "DCOffsetCh0", "DCOffsetCh1", "DCOffsetCh2", 
    "LaserPower", "LaserCurrent", "LaserTemperature", 
    "LaserRunHour", "FlowRate", "FlowPressure", 
    "FlowTemperature", "CpuTemperature", "PwbTemperature", 
    "Temperature1", "Temperature2", "Temperature3", 
    "Temperature4", "TotalParticles", "Bio"     
from (
    select distinct on ("Results"."Timestamp")
        "Results"."Timestamp", 
        "TotalParticlesAccum", "BioAccumulated", "FlowVolume", 
        "DCOffsetCh0", "DCOffsetCh1", "DCOffsetCh2", 
        "LaserPower", "LaserCurrent", "LaserTemperature", 
        "LaserRunHour", "FlowRate", "FlowPressure", 
        "FlowTemperature", "CpuTemperature", "PwbTemperature", 
        "Temperature1", "Temperature2", "Temperature3", 
        "Temperature4", "TotalParticles", "Bio" 
    from
        "Results"
        Left join
        "SensorLog" On "Results"."SampleID" = "SensorLog"."SampleID"
    where "Results"."SampleID" = id
    order by 1 asc
) s
```

Comment: that sounds like a good idea, but i get an error: missing from-clause entry for table "Results"
LINE 1: select to_char("Results"."Timestamp",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'...

Comment: @Ubaldo I don't see it in the code I posted. Can you just copy and paste?

Comment: Sorry my bad, that work out great Thanks!, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is use the raw field for the grouping and ordering but format it the way you want in the select clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Timestamp")
    to_char("Results"."Timestamp", 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
    ,"TotalParticlesAccum"
    ,"BioAccumulated"
    ,"FlowVolume"
    ,"DCOffsetCh0"
    ,"DCOffsetCh1"
    ,"DCOffsetCh2"
    ,"LaserPower"
    ,"LaserCurrent"
    ,"LaserTemperature"
    ,"LaserRunHour"
    ,"FlowRate"
    ,"FlowPressure"
    ,"FlowTemperature"
    ,"CpuTemperature"
    ,"PwbTemperature"
    ,"Temperature1"
    ,"Temperature2"
    ,"Temperature3"
    ,"Temperature4"
    ,"TotalParticles"
    ,"Bio"
FROM "Results"
Left join "SensorLog" On "Results"."SampleID" = "SensorLog"."SampleID"
WHERE "Results"."SampleID" = 839
ORDER BY "Timestamp" ASC
```

Without an sqlfiddle I'm not 100% that this will run, but it is likely the right track to take.

Comment: @Andreas the OP had a Carthesian product in his original question which has now been replaced by a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

**Timestamp** is a reserved word; You can't name a column **timestamp** without issues. Try changing it.